# itemize equations

Tags: equations, itemize

I would like to itemize some equations but they don't appear on the same line as the bullets.

Here is a code example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item\begin{equation*}
         Pr( Y= n)  = \frac{e^{-7}\times 7^n}{n!}
\end{equation*}

\item\begin{equation*}              
         Pr(X = m)  = \frac{e^{-4}\times 4^m}{m!}
\end{equation*}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please change your given code snippet to a complete [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use inline equations, you can make them bigger by using `\displaystyle`. You can also achieve the same for fractions by using `\dfrac` from the `amsmath` package (thanks @cmhughes for the suggestion).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
    \item $ Pr( Y= n)  = \frac{e^{-7}\times 7^n}{n!} $
    \item $ Pr(X = m)  = \frac{e^{-4}\times 4^m}{m!} $
    \item $ \displaystyle Pr( Y= n)  = \frac{e^{-7}\times 7^n}{n!} $
    \item $ \displaystyle Pr(X = m)  = \frac{e^{-4}\times 4^m}{m!} $
    \item $ Pr( Y= n)  = \dfrac{e^{-7}\times 7^n}{n!} $
    \item $ Pr(X = m)  = \dfrac{e^{-4}\times 4^m}{m!} $
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: Equations]

Comment: +1 could you add the option to use `\dfrac` from the `amsmath` package too?

Comment: How can one number each of these equations (in a manner similar to the equation environment)?