# Lists of displayed math

Tags: lists

How do I format a list of questions like this?

[image]

I'm getting the equation on a new line below the i) when using enumerate and `\list`.

I don't want to get rid of `\[` and `\]` either as I like the long integral sign

I get this instead:

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Related questions: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9394/vertical-alignment-of-align-in-enumerate http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78574/itemize-equations http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3109/displaying-an-equation-in-a-list http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9383/align-number-from-enumerate-with-equation

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
\begin{enumerate}
\item[(i)]
$\displaystyle\int_0^{\pi}\frac{x\sin{x}}{3+\sin^2{x}}\,\mathrm{d}x$
\end{enumerate}
```

and so on.

Answer (score 3):

At a guess (it's hard to experiment without sample code) try: `\(\displaystyle <your expression>\)`.